# xpdf copy & paste and unicode

Tags: debian, pdf, unicode, xpdf

Since updating to debian jessie I have a problem with copy and paste from PDF files using xpdf: only letters/symbols contained in ASCII are copied correctly. All other symbols/letters are in some way garbeld.

For example I have a PDF file containg the German word "Würde". Copying it from xpdf and pasting it I get: "WÃ¼rde". Other PDF readers (e.g. acroread, zathura) work ok. The problem arrises with all PDF files containing non ASCII text/symbols.

In /etc/xpdf/xpdfrc I have:

textEncoding            UTF-8

I tested it with Latin1 and ASCII, but there was no change at all. (There is no .xpdfrc in my home folder.)

```
> locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

> locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE.utf8
POSIX
```

Any suggestions how I could get copy and paste working again?

Comment: `Ã¼` seems to be how the binary data is displayed when interpreting the UTF-8 encoding of `ü` as ISO-8859-1 or -15, which might be a clue here. (*Something* on your system is likely talking ISO-8859-1/15 when it should be talking UTF-8.) Please [edit] your question to include the output of running both `locale` and `locale -a` on your system.

Comment: As with other pdfviewers copy&paste works ok I was thinking that this _something_ should be something very "near" to xpdf itself. What besides xpdf could that be? (I added the output of the two commands you recommended.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the result of two bugs of Debian's xpdf:

[#737989](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=737989) describes the problem (selection of non-ASCII characters no longer works) and provides a patch in two patch files. Unfortunately applying the patch doesn't solve the problem.

This is linked to a second bug [#739271](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=739271) (many config file directives not working). Applying *additionally* to the patch above the patches provided here (poppler-xpdfparams, poppler-gfile-dedupe -- second one probably not necessary) and changing `/debian/patches/series` and `/debian/rules` as explained in message #22 to this bug, seems to resolve the problem.

To prevent cluttering of the screen with too many error messages I also commented out the line `include /etc/xpdf/includes` in `/etc/xpdf/xpdfrc`.